# Patient admitted to ICU after cardiac arrest (post cardiac arrest) in MIMIC-III

Tags: uses-of-open-data, mimic-iii

How to select patients in the MIMIC-III database admitted to ICU immediately after a cardiac arrest? Although ICD-9-CM 427.5 is related to cardiac arrest, it is unclear to select the patients admitted in the context of a successful resuscitation also called ROSC (return of spontaneous circulation). Patients with a successful resuscitation in the medical history can be admitted to ICU in the context of another event.

Answer (score 1):

In the CHARTEVENTS table, the event code `4545` is associated with an episode of CPR, which typically follows an arrest (unless a patient has a DNR order). Also, in the PROCEDUREEVENTS_MV table, the codes `225475` and `224566` represent cardiac and respiratory arrests, respectively. On manual review, however, not all of these episodes appear as true arrests. On approach may be to mine the text notes to look for a reported history of arrest but I haven't tried that myself.